# .NET Core Entitiy Framework Get Mutiple Table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

[Sql Tables Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH3hP.png)

```
public partial class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
        UsersRelationFollower = new HashSet<UsersRelation>();
        UsersRelationFollowing = new HashSet<UsersRelation>();
        Vote = new HashSet<Vote>();
        VoteRating = new HashSet<VoteRating>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public bool State { get; set; }


    public virtual UserPasswords UserPasswords { get; set; }
    public virtual CorporateProperty CorporateProperty { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProperty UserProperty { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UsersRelation> UsersRelationFollower { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UsersRelation> UsersRelationFollowing { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vote> Vote { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VoteRating> VoteRating { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserProperty
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool State { get; set; }

    public virtual Users IdNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class CorporateProperty
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string OrganisationName { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public bool State { get; set; }

    public virtual Users IdNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

UserControllerClass

```
// GET: api/Users/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers([FromRoute] string id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var users = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (users == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(users);
    }
```

My problem is exactly this; User information is coming but the password and property table information is not coming.

How to modify the following line solves my problem?

```
var users = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

Comment: Are you storing passwords in plain text? If so that's a big no no.

Comment: No, I do not store the passwords in plain text. I am just trying to learn the entitiy framework and .net core

Comment: As stated by mvermef I would look into Identity as Microsoft has this functionality built in and takes care of the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your code this would also hydrate your CorporateProperty & UseProperty objects, etc.

```
var user = await _context.Users.Include(user => user.UserProperty).Include
(user => user.CorporateProperty).SingleOrDefaultAsync(user => user.Id == id);
```

lazy loading doesn't exist yet so you have Eager Loading to play with for now.

Surprised you didn't roll with Identity since this all of this would have been taken care for you especially Passwords...  Hope you aren't rolling your own hash for that..

Just add in the custom class / collection objects you need.

you can also check out this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data